# Salary range and hiring

Tags: salary, negotiation

Job applications sometimes list salary ranges, they also ask for people to give them what their expected salary is.

Is there a downside to listing the bottom range? I want a remote position and will take less for it. If I list bottom will they counter with something even lower?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [should you tell a possible employer what's the minimum amount you are willing to work for?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17344/should-you-tell-a-possible-employer-whats-the-minimum-amount-you-are-willing-to)

Comment: how badly do you want the job - how badly does the company probably think you want the job? If you could take it or leave it, you have the bargaining power to ask higher. (I accidentally got a $30k raise this way)

Answer (score 9):

I, personally, would never list at the bottom range.

Firstly is confidence - I have skills the company needs, I know the value of those skills. If I sell those skills short, then the person hiring may doubt how good they are.

Secondly is that the value of your time is not dependent on where you live. Even if you are happy to accept a lower amount due to lower costs of living.

That said - if you are happy to accept near the bottom, I would start at the middle range, or perhaps just below - wait for the negotiation to start - if they are happy to pay that amount, then you've got a little more. If they aren't, then you can haggle down:

"I would like $X, it's the middle of your salary bracket"
"Well, we feel for a candidate like you, that's too high"
"Okay, considering that I'm remote and my costs of living are lower, I could come down to $Y"
"We think $Y is doable! Welcome aboard!"